# Object Oriented Programming in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider an OOP model. I wanted to implement,

```
funct1( arg ).subfunct1( arg ); (
```

Of course like jQuery. where you have `$( arg ).subfn( arg )`

I have done it successfully for one subfunction. BUT,

```
funct1( arg ).subfunct1( arg ); // ==> works fine.
funct1( arg ).subfunct1( arg ).subfunct( arg ); // ==> doesnt work.
```

Source is:

```
var funct1=function() { 
    var dummy=new Object(); 
    dummy.subfunct1=bla bla; 
    dummy.subfunct2=bla bla; 
    return dummy; 
}
```

Can you say any remedies.

Answer (score 3):

`subfunct1` has to `return this` in order to have chainable calls.

Answer (score 0):

That only works in jQuery, because most functions are setup to return the jQuery object that they are a part of (`this`), after modification, so that they can be chained together.

What do your functions return?

Answer (score 0):

There's a method to enable chainable calls on any object **without** `return this`:

```
function chain(obj) {
    return function() {
        var Self = arguments.callee; Self.obj = obj;
        if(arguments.length==0) return Self.obj;
        Self.obj[arguments[0]].apply(Self.obj,[].slice.call(arguments,1));
        return Self;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function ClassA() {
    this.prop1 = null;
    this.prop2 = null;
    this.prop3 = null;
}

ClassA.prototype = {
    method1: function(argu) {this.prop1 = argu;},
    method2: function(argu) {this.prop2 = argu;},
    method3: function(argu) {this.prop3 = argu;}
}

var a = new ClassA();
chain(a)('method1',4)('method2',5)('method3',6)();
```

ref: http://www.javaeye.com/topic/748348 (in Chinese)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions :), btw I tried a few hours as I'm not conceptually strong and got an working procedure as follows..

```
var funct1=function() { 
    var dummy=new Object(); 
    var clone=dummy;
    dummy.subfunct1=bla bla; //you have to return every time the clone object 
    dummy.subfunct2=bla bla; //you have to return every time the clone object 
    return dummy; 
}
```

thus the function (anyway) become chained to n times.
Hope this helps anyone who searches as me :)